# CMIS query is working in alfresco node browser but not in session.query()

Tags: alfresco, cmis, apache-chemistry

I am using below code for retrieving some object based on creation date

```
String query = ContentCleaningUtil.buildQuery(fileNamePattern, uTCTimeString);
OperationContext opCon = session.createOperationContext();
opCon.setLoadSecondaryTypeProperties(true);
opCon.setMaxItemsPerPage(1000);
ItemIterable<QueryResult> results = session.query(query, false, opCon);
```

I am getting empty results.

The query String is:

```
SELECT * FROM cmis:document WHERE cmis:name LIKE '%.zip' AND cmis:creationDate > TIMESTAMP '2018-09-01T22:56:44.248Z'
```

But when I am firing same query in alfresco node browser setting query as cmis-alfresco, it is returning 2 desired objects.

In both case I am using store workspace://Spacestore

Can anyone please help on this.

Comment: Please let me clarify that query with other timestamps like,
SELECT * FROM cmis:document WHERE (cmis:name LIKE '%.zip') AND (cmis:creationDate > TIMESTAMP '2018-09-01T22:56:44.248Z')   is working with session.query()

Comment: What happens when you run it in the node browser using "cmis-strict" instead of "cmis-alfresco"?